# Bash reserved words vs. built-in commands, and formatting the output of the time command

Tags: bash

What's the difference between bash reserved words and built-in commands?

Can I disable bash's time, and use `/usr/bin/time`? If not, how can I format its output?

Comment: There is actually an environment variable: TIMEFORMAT that specifies the output of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most reserved words are commands that are built into bash; if you want to use an executable that has the same name as a reserved word then either specify the full path to the executable, or escape the command with a backslash.

```
$ time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ \time
Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--help] command [arg...]
$ then
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
$ \then
bash: then: command not found
```

Also, [BASH FAQ #32: "How can I redirect the output of 'time' to a variable or file?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

Comment: Strictly speaking, reserved words aren't necessarily commands at all, as your example even demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `builtin <cmd>` and `command <cmd>` to force calling a bash built-in or an external command.